# GoogleMaps "SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control"

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I use this code to display a Google Map with Markers. But now it throws an error. **"SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control"** Knows someone why?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you view the source of the actual page, you will see that the script is actually

```
;for(var i=0;i&lt;locations.length;i++){
```

Something escape the < sign.